# Angular $watch nuance and factory not reflecting state change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory, watch

I have difficulty grasping why the factory will not reflect changes to its primitives (as a singleton) but it will to objects.. sometimes.. in the following six scenarios.

I have this factory:

```
angular.module('my.module).factory('myfactory', FactoryFunction);
function FactoryFunction(){

  var primitiveVariable = false;
  function togglePrimitive(){
    primitiveVariable = !primitiveVariable
  }
  var dummyObject = {
    isTrue = false;
  }
  function toggleObject(){
    dummyObject.isTrue = !dummyObject.isTrue;
  }
  var myFactory = {
    toggleObject: toggleObject,
    dummyObject: dummyObject,
    togglePrimitive: togglePrimitive,
    primitiveVariable: primitiveVariable
   }
   return myFactory
}
```

and I also have this directive

```
angular.module('my.module).directive('myDirective', DirectiveFunction);
DirectiveFunction.$inject['myFactory'];
function DirectiveFunction(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope:{},
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, nullcontroller, nulltranslcude){

      //watch1 WONT RUN 
      //watched is undefined even if myFactory.togglePrimitive() runs
      scope.$watch(myFactory.primitiveVariable, function(){
        //do stuff
      });

      //watch2 WONT RUN
      //watched is undefined even if myFactory.togglePrimitive() runs
      scope.$watch(function(){return myFactory.primitiveVariable}, function(){
        //do stuff
      });

      //watch3 WONT RUN
      //not returning something by calling togglePrimitive()?
      scope.$watch(myFactory.togglePrimitive(), function(){
        //do stuff
      });

      //watch4 WILL RUN
      //but now I am not even running the function...?
      scope.$watch(myFactory.togglePrimitive, function(){
        //do stuff
      });

      //watch5 WONT RUN
      scope.$watch(myFactory.dummyObject.isTrue, function(){
        //do stuff
      });

      //watch6 WILL RUN 
      //... seriously??
      //is myObj.val and function(){return myObj.val} NOT the same?
      scope.$watch(function(){return myFactory.dummyObject.isTrue}, function(){
        //do stuff
      });
    }
  }
}
```

My question is, why do watch1, watch2, watch3, watch5, NOT work while watch4, wantch6 DO work?

I am interested in the why this happens. Is this a design choice? what is the purpose?

Also I would like to add that function(){ return myFactory.primitiveValue } does not work as a watch expression and yet function(){ return myFactory.dummyObject.isTrue } works as a watch expression. Does anyone know why this bias occurs between primitive vs object's primitive attribute? They are both primitives. When console.log from the factory function that updates the primitive, it reflects the change. When console.log from the expression that returns the primitive (in the $watch), it does not reflect the change.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b0svnjqf/21/

Any light anyone can shine into this I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because watch expression takes either a string representing the property or an expression that can be evaluated on that scope or a function getter that returns a value which is used for dirty checking every digest cycle.

So for example:

```
  scope.$watch(myFactory.primitiveVariable, function(){
    //do stuff
  });
```

watch expression is the value of `myFactory.primitiveVariable` and not the property itself, where as:

```
  scope.$watch(function(){return myFactory.primitiveVariable}, function(){
    //do stuff
  });
```

runs the expression getter passed in as function during every digest cycle for dirty check which will return the value of the property at that time.

Similarly when you do :

```
  scope.$watch(myFactory.togglePrimitive, function(){
    //do stuff
  });
```

you are passing the reference to the function `togglePrimitive` as the watch expression which can be a getter but you are really not returning anything from there so your watch listener will not run after 1 iteration.

[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch):

> watchExpression:   function() | string
>
> Expression that is evaluated on each $digest cycle. A change in the return value triggers a call to the listener.
>
> string: Evaluated as expression
>
> function(scope): called with current scope as a parameter.

Apart from this there is no point changing the variable `primitiveVariable` and expect the change to be reflected magically in `myFactory.primitiveVariable` they both are different and as they are primitive they don't hold on to the references as well.

```
function FactoryFunction(){
    
  var myFactory ,
      dummyObject = {
         isTrue = false;
      };

  function togglePrimitive(){
    //Set the value directly on the factory instance
    myFactory.primitiveVariable = !myFactory.primitiveVariable
    //or even this.primitiveVariable  = !this.primitiveVariable;
    //But better not to assume "this" as much as you can
  }
  
  function toggleObject(){
     //This is fine as you are modifying property on the reference and the same reference has been set to the dummyObject property of myFactory
     dummyObject.isTrue = !dummyObject.isTrue;
     //or this.dummyObject.isTrue = !this.dummyObject.isTrue;
  }

  myFactory = {
     toggleObject: toggleObject,
     dummyObject: dummyObject, //this should be fine unless you overwrite the variable dummyObject itself
     togglePrimitive: togglePrimitive,
     primitiveVariable: false //Set the value directly
   }  
  
   return myFactory;
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. Could you please provide some source so that I can go off and read until my slow-brain gets it? :D Also: why does myFactory.togglePrimitive work and not myFactory.togglePrimitive()? is myFactory.togglePrimitive() not a getter function, but rather, the result of such?

Comment: `myFactory.togglePrimitive()` is not a getter function you are invoking it right away and setting the value as watch expression

Comment: Thank you, I have been glaring at this page and with your help i think I am beginning to get it... do you know why function(){ return myFactory.primitiveValue } does not work as a watch expression and yet function(){ return myFactory.dummyObject.isTrue } works as a watch expression? is angular prejudice towards primitive variables? D:

Comment: First one will also work. But not working, what do you mean? It will run the evaluation function every digest cycle, you can do a console logging but listener will run only if values are different. If you are planning to compare object then you would need to set third argument of watch to true so that it does a deep comparison otherwise it will only check for object equality `===`.

Comment: @kilogic See my answer update with factory code revised

Comment: By 'not working' I mean the listener function in the $watch(expression, listener) does not run. This is consistent even if I do primitiveVariable: false in the object that the factory definition returns, AND if I define it within the factory var primitiveVariable: false and then in the return object {primitiveVariable:primitiveVariable} - my point is, that when I am comparing/watching a primitive of a factory, it does not detect the change; with console.log in the watch expression, it always logs 'false'. I will provide a jsFiddle tonight. Thank you for telling me about the true flag.

Comment: thanks. I will do more of that. I still dont understand why the expression wont show the updated value for the factory when returning a primitive vs returning an object's primitive attribute. I agree that you answered the difference between toggleObject and toggleObject(). but not the primitive vs object bit of my question.

Comment: @kilogic your original question was related to watch. primitive vs object is something basic in javascript (or any other language) which i suggest you should research upon. Also explanation with the comments on my answer on your factory code should be sufficient enough i believe. There is no pass by ref in javascript even when you pass an object to a function a copy of its reference is passed as value.

Comment: When you set a variable "primitiveVariable" later after assigning its _value_ to property of object "myFactory" it is not going to get reflected as you are not updating the property on the same object instead you are just updating a variable. You are expecting that when you do say "primitiveVariable = !primitiveVariable" it will change "myFactory.primitiveVariable" as well which is wrong. You can right away console log both of them in the factory itself.

Comment: Thank you. I was under the impression that the factory was a singleton object, so when it updated one of its properties, it would be reflected in all the references to this same singleton object. I will go again and read read read so that I can understand why this isn't so. Once I understand this comment, which is like the answer I was looking for, and find a way to prove it I guess. I will accept this as the answer.

Comment: @kilogic for proof you can just debug, console.log yourself and yes factory is a singleton, but you are not updating its property but you were updating a variable. Try the factory revision i have in my answer, that should shed some light i hope. Cheers!!

Comment: why is the change to the factory not reflected? I did console.log. The factory was updated. The reference to the factory in the directive was not.

Comment: @kilogic Use that and paste it in a working fiddle and please share it in the comment, il try to explain it tonight.